# How to know the number of types in the elastic search index

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my question description

- I created elastic search index named **testindex**
- curl -XPUT 'localhost:8080/testindex/type1/id1?pretty=true'
- As of now i know my testindex has one type i.e type1
- I have one more index called **anotherindex**,i want to know how many types in **anotherindex** by seeing index name itself.
- How to know.Is there any curl command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the get mapping command:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/anotherindex/_mapping?pretty'
```

The command will list all the mappings for index anotherindex.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html

Comment: This returns entire anotherindex mapping including all types.This is good.any other command to know only specific types?